# Boas práticas para trafegar objeto JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localstorage

Possuo um grid (kendo ui MVC) hoje possui 35163 linhas, e preciso criar um botão para exportar o conteúdo do grid para CSV.

Pensei em fazer algo assim, no momento em que carrego as informações para alimentar o grid, gerar um objeto JSON e armazenar esse objeto na sessionStorage, aí quando for gerar o CSV, basta pegar esses dados e enviar para controller, não precisando refazer outra consulta na base de dados.

Se fizer como descrevi acima, pode prejudicar a performance?
Alguém tem alguma ideia melhor, qual?

Comment: É melhor você guardar ela em sessão do que refazer a consulta, não vejo nenhum problema no que você está propondo.

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo problemas em refazer a consulta e gerar o arquivo CSV. É muito registro pra se colocar na Session, com vários acessos de diferentes usuários, pode facilmente sobrecarregar a memória do servidor.
Recomendo refazer a consulta e gerar o arquivo CSV. Pense em mudar esse grid com tantos registros e utilizar recursos de paginação.